# Почему не стартует Tomcat (OS не дает доступ к catalina.sh)?

Tags: java, tomcat

Я пытаюсь запустить Tomcat но получаю вот такую ошибку:

> rror running 'CarMag': Cannot run program
>   "/Users/MyMac/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22/bin/catalina.sh" (in
>   directory "/Users/MyMac/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22/bin"):
>   error=13, Permission denied

Почему может быть отказано в доступе? И как это исправить? Все происходит под Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

`/Users/MyMac/Documents/` это не служебная директория. Возможно тут есть какие-то тонкости связанные с паролями пользователя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае, если Tomcat был просто распакован из архива, у скрипта `catalina.sh` может не быть прав на запуск (или нет таких прав для текущего пользователя). Добавить их можно командой `chmod +x catalina.sh` для текущего пользователя или `chmod 777 catalina.sh` для всех пользователей.

Это справедливо для всех Unix-подобных систем, одной из которых и является macOS.